# Does an API for searching for Windows 8 App updates exist

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-update, windows-store

Microsft provide and API for interfacing with Windows Update through [Windows Update Agent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They also provide an API for managing installing, updating and uninstalling App packages through the [Windows.Management.Deployment namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240983.aspx).

Updating an app requires you to have the URI of the update, unfortunately I can't figure out how to search for Windows Store updates programatically rather than though the Store application.

Comment: Are you wanting to search for updates to your own app, or for updates to some other app?

Comment: I'm hoping to be able to search for updates for other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to this [blog post - Search updates using the Windows Store](http://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/search-updates-using-the-windows-store/).